# Geth and Lighthouse peers are added, but none of them are downloading / importing blocks from peers?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, network, peers, lighthouse

i am trying to run a private PoS network on a private organizational network (all ips are accessible only if you're connected to organization's intranet )

I am using geth as Execution Client and lighthouse as Consensus Client. The PoS network runs flawlessly on node A / machine A ( with network ip 1 )

but when i try to create redundancy, by initialising lighthouse and geth on node B / machine B ( with network ip 2 ) , the geth at B does not does not sync with the geth at node A.

The lighthouse at machine B is able to detect the lighthouse at machine A, BUT it demands the its own execution client ( the geth on machine B, attached to the lighthouse at machine B ) must also be synced before it can start syncing all the blocks.

I have proof that the lighthouse client at machine B is able to detect the lighthouse client at machine A.

[image: lighthouse beacon node output for machine A and B, side by side]

This shows the beacon node outputs for machine A and B, side by side. as you can see Node B actually knows the same number of slots as Node A, BUT cannot start donwloading blocks. This indicates that lighthouse of Node B is connected with lighthouse of Node A

now for the geth, the peers are added and i can show you the admin output of each node;

Node A geth details:

[image: Node A geth node details]

Node B geth node details:

[image: Node B geth node details]

Node B's geth added as a peer on Node A geth:

[image: Node B's geth added as a peer on Node A geth]

Node A's geth added as a peer on Node B geth:

[image: Node A's geth added as a peer on Node B geth]

as you can see from the pictures, both geth instances are peers of each other, YET node B's geth does not import any blocks from node A ?!

please help me resolve this